# Is there a point at which spaghettification is highest?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, tidal-effect

I've read anything getting close to a *regular* black hole would experience **spaghettification** but not when you get close to *super-massive* black hole.

Is there a point of **"peak spaghettification"** where the mass of the black hole exerts the greatest tidal force? Or, have I misunderstood something along the way?

Comment: AFAIK, the tidal forces will always get larger as the black hole gets smaller since they are proportional to (powers of?) $r_\text{head}/r_\text{feet}$ (distances measured from the singularity).

Comment: @Danu the tidal forces at the event horizon are inversely proportional to the mass of the black hole, but the tidal forces at a particular distance from the singularity are directly proportional to the black hole mass.

Answer (score 6):

A tidal force happens because different parts of the infalling object are trying to move along different geodesics. Suppose we take the 3-vector $\eta$ to be the distance between two points, then we can calculate how $\eta$ changes as the object falls inwards. If $\eta$ is constant then the distance between the points isn't changing and there is no tidal force. If $\eta$ is increasing then the points are being stretched apart while if $\eta$ is decreasing the points are being compressed together.

Anyhow, after some frenzied pen scratching (the details can be found in any GR textbook) we get:

$$ \frac{D^2\eta^r}{d\tau^2} = \frac{r_s}{r^3}\eta^r $$

$$ \frac{D^2\eta^\theta}{d\tau^2} = -\frac{r_s}{2r^3}\eta^\theta $$

$$ \frac{D^2\eta^\phi}{d\tau^2} = -\frac{r_s}{2r^3}\eta^\phi $$

where $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the spatial Schwarzschild coordinates and $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius $r_s = 2GM/c^2$. $D$ is the covariant derivative. The quantities on the left hand side are effectively an acceleration, so they are a force per unit mass that we can interpret as a tidal force.

The point of all this is that the tidal forces are proportional to $1/r^3$. This means they are greatest at $r \rightarrow 0$ i.e. they reach a maximum as the infalling object reaches the singularity.

Note that the tidal forces are finite at any value of $r \gt 0$ so they are finite at the event horizon. In fact at the horizon, i.e. when $r = r_s$, we get (I'll show just the radial equation):

$$ \frac{D^2\eta^r}{d\tau^2} = \frac{1}{r_s^2}\eta^r = \frac{c^4}{4G^2M^2}\eta^r $$

So the tidal force at the horizon decreases as the inverse square of the black hole mass.

Comment: This is late, but could you point me towards a textbook that gives the detailed derivations of the geodesic deviation equations? The textbook I'm using (Schutz First Course in General Relativity) doesn't have it, and I'm struggling to derive them myself.