# $\hat{\phi}$ tidal acceleration of a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, tidal-effect

For Schwarzchild geometry I've calculated the tidal acceleration in the $\hat{\phi}$ direction for two particles initially at rest separated by $\Delta \phi.$
$$a^a = -R_{cbd}{}^aX^b T^c T^d$$
Where $X^b = (0,0,0,\Delta \phi),$ and $T^c = \left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}, 0,0,0\right).$
This gives
$$a^3 = -R_{030}{}^3\left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right)^2 d\phi = \frac{-ME^2}{r^3 \left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)} \Delta \phi.$$

I'm next asked, given the tolerance of the human body, what size of a black hole could a human survive when crossing the event horizon. But this predicts an infinite tidal acceleration at $r=2M.$ (Notice that this is different than the usual problem of calculating the tidal acceleration in the $\hat{r}$ direction, in that case there is no divergence at $r=2M$).

So what is going on here? Have I just miscalculated $a^3$?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, given the correct choice of coordinates, one can make the diverging factor disappear. See the answer to this question which does not contain $(1-\frac{2M}{r})$: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/is-there-a-point-at-which-spaghettification-is-highest